# An elegant way to wrap another script for error handling in python and keeping the same commandline API

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a script which I would like to wrap with an error handler that send an email if the script fails.

The straight-forward way to do it is:

```
try:
  <script imports>
  <script argument parse>
  <script contents>
except Exception as e:
  send_email(e)
  raise
```

However I feel this solution is cumbersome. What are more elegant ways of doing it, while keeping the same commandline API of the original script?

EDIT: it would be great to have a solution with an API like: `python email_wrap.py script_to_run.py <arguments>`. However, I am not sure how to manipulate the commandline arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(OP here) I found how to do it:

#### email_wrap.py

```
import runpy

try:
    scriptname_to_wrap = sys.argv[1]
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv[2:]

    runpy.run_path(scriptname_to_wrap, run_name="__main__")

except BaseException as e:
    send_email(e)
    raise
```